# how to implement a search bar in ionic

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

How can i add a search functionality into a angular and ionic project. I tried doing this with the following code below but it doesn't work.

This is the code i tried

```
 filterusers(evt)
  {
  const search = evt.srcElement.value;
  console.log(search);
  if(!search)
  {
    return;
  }

  this.employees = this.employees.filter(currentgoal =>
    {
    if(currentgoal.FName && search)
    {
      if(currentgoal.FName.toLowerCase().indexof(search.toLowerCase()) > -1)
      {
        return true;
      }
      return false;
    }
    });
  }
```

how can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try below way

```
empData : any = [];

filterusers(evt)
{
  const search = evt.srcElement.value;
  if(!search)
  {
    return;
  }
  this.empData = this.employees;
  let filtered = this.empData.filter((x) =>
    x.FName.toLocaleLowerCase().replace(/ /g, "").includes(search.toLocaleLowerCase().replace(/ /g, "")));
  this.employees= filtered;
  if (!filtered.length) {
    //no record found
  }
}
```

also you can use search npm like [ng2-search-filter](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-search-filter)

Comment: the above code didn't work but i used the package and it was really helpful. Thank you :)

Comment: Yes @Silent it's great to use package.and you also need to find why it not worked. because when you call api and store the data to "this.employees" that time also  you need to assign empData array." this.empData = this.employees;"